# Task.Run and expected delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, lambda, delegates

I am not sure how to make sense out of the following observed results.

```
var f = new Func<CancellationToken,string>(uc.ViewModel.SlowProcess);

1) (VALID) string dataPromise = await Task.Run<string>(() => f(token), token);

2) (VALID) string dataPromise = await Task.Run<string>(() => uc.ViewModel.SlowProcess(token), token);

3) (ERROR) string dataPromise = await Task.Run<string>(f(token), token);
```

uc.ViewModel.SlowProcess is a method that takes a CancellationToken as a parameter and returns a string.

Item 1) and 2) are valid and work correctly.  Item 3) is invalid, giving the follow errors:

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Func>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Func>'

Why can't I pass f(token) as a delegate?  If I do it with a method  that takes no parameters, it also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `f(token)` as a delegate is actually what you're doing in (1).

`() => f(token)` is a delegate with no arguments and return type `string`.

`f(token)` is not a delegate, but an immediate invocation of method `f` that  returns a string. That means, your code isn't called by the Task infrastructure, but by yourself, before the Task is even created, resulting in a string. You can't create a Task from that string, which leads to the syntax error.

I would stick with what you did in (1).

---

**Edit: Let's clarify things a bit.**

> IL code probably shows all.

Probably, but we should rather try to understand what the code actually means. We can do this using [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com), the .NET Compiler Platform:

1. Create a new Unit Test Project in Visual Studio.
2. Show the Package Manager Console (from View > Other Windows) and enter `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Pre`
3. Create a new class containing the following code:

   ```
   using System;
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

   public class SyntaxTreeWriter : CSharpSyntaxWalker
   {
       public static void Write(string code)
       {
           var options = new CSharpParseOptions(kind: SourceCodeKind.Script);
           var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code, options);
           new SyntaxTreeWriter().Visit(syntaxTree.GetRoot());
       }

       private static int Indent = 0;
       public override void Visit(SyntaxNode node)
       {
           Indent++;
           var indents = new String(' ', Indent * 2);
           Console.WriteLine(indents + node.CSharpKind());
           base.Visit(node);
           Indent--;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now, let's create a Test Class and analyze your statements from above:

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void Statement_1()
   {
       SyntaxTreeWriter.Write("Task.Run<string>(() => f(token), token)");
   }

   [TestMethod]
   public void Statement_2()
   {
       SyntaxTreeWriter.Write("Task.Run<string>(() => uc.ViewModel.SlowProcess(token), token)");
   }

   [TestMethod]
   public void Statement_3()
   {
       SyntaxTreeWriter.Write("Task.Run<string>(f(token), token)");
   }
   ```
5. For each case, we get some common output:

   ```
   (...)
     InvocationExpression             | Task.Run<string>(..., token)
       SimpleMemberAccessExpression   | Task.Run<string>
         IdentifierName               | Task
         GenericName                  |      Run<string>
           TypeArgumentList           |         <string>
             PredefinedType           |          string
       ArgumentList                   |                 (..., token)
         Argument                     |                  ...
           (...)                      |                  ...
         Argument                     |                       token
           IdentifierName             |                       token
   ```
6. For (1) and (2), we get the following argument:

   ```
   ParenthesizedLambdaExpression      | () => ...()
     ParameterList                    | ()
     InvocationExpression             |    => ...()
       (...)                          |       ...
   ```
7. For (3) instead, we get the following argument:

   ```
   InvocationExpression               | f(token)
     IdentifierName                   | f
     ArgumentList                     |  (token)
       Argument                       |   token
         IdentifierName               |   token
   ```

### Ok, what do we have here?

A `ParenthesizedLambdaExpression` obviously is an inline method declaration. The type of this expression is determined by the **parameter list** (input), the type of the **lambda body** (output) and by the **expected type** where the lambda is used (type inference).

What does that mean?

- Our lambdas in (1) and (2) have an empty parameter list and thereby no input.
- In both lambdas, we invoke something (method or delegate) that returns a string.
- That means, the type of our lambda expression will be one of the following:

  - `Func<string>`
  - `Expression<Func<string>>`
  - `Action`
  - `Expression<Action>`
- The type of the first argument of our Task.Run method determines which type is used. We have the following possibilities, given that we use an overload that takes a `CancellationToken` as second parameter:

  - `Action`
  - `Func<TResult>`
  - `Func<Task>`
  - `Func<Task<TResult>>`
- There are two matching types:

  - `Func<string>`, where TResult is `string`
  - `Action`
- The first one has higher precedence, so we use the overload `Task.Run<string>(Func<string>, CancellationToken)`

Okay. That's why (1) and (2) both work: They use a lambda, which in fact generates a delegate, and the type of the delegate matches the expectations of the `Task.Run` method.

Why is `f(token)` not working then?

> Once you accept that passing a parameterized delegate essentially gets treated like passing the function(s) it wraps, everything works like you would expect.

There is no such thing as a "parameterized delegate". There are delegates that have parameters (`Action<T>`, `Func<T,TResult>`...) but this is fundamentally different from `f(token)` which is an invocation of delegate f, which results in the return value of the delegated method. That's why the type of `f(token)` simply is `string`:

- The type of an InvocationExpression is the return type of the called method. The same applies to delegates.
- The type of `f(token)` is `string`, because `f` has been declared as `Func<CancellationToken,string>`.
- Our overloads for `Task.Run` still take:

  - `Action`
  - `Func<TResult>`
  - `Func<Task>`
  - `Func<Task<TResult>>`
- There is no match. Code's not compiling.

How could we make it work?

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<CancellationToken, TResult> function, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Func<TResult> wrappedFunction = () => function(token);
        return Task.Run(wrappedFunction, token);
    }
}
```

This could be called like `TaskExtensions.Run(f, token)`. But I would not recommend doing that, as it provides no additional value whatsoever.

Additional information:

[EBNF Syntax: C# 1.0/2.0/3.0/4.0](http://www.externsoft.ch/download/csharp.html) 
[C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I know what you are saying is correct, but f is an instance of Func, so it is a delegate. Seems like you need to wrap a delegate in a delegate (ie, wrapping f in a lambda) to get it to work correctly.  Seems like there should be a way to pass f without wrapping it in a lambda.

Comment: @Bill: Take another look at the code `Task.Run<string>(f(token), token)`. As Frank says, the code `f(token)` is not passing `f` as a delegate; it's *calling* `f`. If you want to pass `f` as a delegate, you'd have to do `Task.Run<string>(f, token)`.

Comment: @Stephen:  Yes, agreed.  So, the reason the lambda expression works is that in (1), because of the parameter given to f, the lambda is essentially wrapping the function uc.ViewModel.SlowProcess - like in (2).  When f is parameterized, it is treated like the function it wraps, whereas when it is just f, it is treated like a ref to a del. If I create a multicast delegate multiF, () => multiF(token) also works.  Once you accept that passing a parameterized delegate essentially gets treated like passing the function(s) it wraps, everything works like you would expect. IL code probably shows all.

Comment: @Frank: Thanks for excellent analysis; sorry for a delayed reply.  I understand that an InvocationExpression gives a value of its return type.  My very small bone to pick comes down to the semantics of the language - there is no way to create the closure you get when you use a lambda expression and bring in an outside variable (here, token) without using a lambda expression.  The C# lang designers made a choice to treat f(token) (where f is a delegate) as an InvocationExpression, and ()=>f(token) (a delegate invoking a delegate) as something else. Your excellent analysis makes this explicit.

Comment: @StephenCleary: As I mention in my (revised) comment to Frank, (pls look for the latest from today :)) my confusion stems from there being no way to create a closure outside of using lambda expressions. Your example `Task.Run<string>(f, token)` does not bring in `token` as a closure parameter to f. Recall f is a delegate, but f(token) does not behave the same as `()=>f(token)`, as made explicit by @Frank 's analysis. It strikes me as a minor inconsistency that `f(token)`, when passed in a param list and where f is a delegate, is treated the same as if f was not a delegate - as an invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate that you are passing into `Task.Run` does not match and any of the expected signatures. It takes in a `CancellationToken` and returns a `string` which does not match any of the [allowed signatures.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Getting rid of the cancellation token allows it to match on of these:

```
Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)  
Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>, CancellationToken)
```